# Media Foundation add audio stream to video file

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, video, ms-media-foundation

I was able to successfully encode an `MP4` file which contains H.264 encoded video only (using **IMFSinkWriter** interface). Now I want to add an audio stream to it.

Whenever I try to create a sink writer for an audio using:

`MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(filePath, null, null, &pSinkWriter)`

it deletes the previous file and writes only the audio (well, according to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfbytestream) it is expected).

So my question is: how to add an audio stream to an existing file which contains only video stream?

Or, If I have both raw data from audio and video how do I encode both of them into a single media file (I suppose I have to do something called multiplexing. If so, can someone provide me helpful references)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sink Writer API creates a media file from scratch when you do `IMFSinkWriter::BeginWriting` to final completion when you do `IMFSinkWriter::Finalize`. You don't add new streams to finalized file (well, you can do it, but it works differently - see last paragraph below).

To create a media file with both video and audio you need to add two streams before you begin. Two calls `IMFSinkWriter::AddStream`, then two `IMFSinkWriter::SetInputMediaType`, then you start writing `IMFSinkWriter::BeginWriting` and you feed both video and audio data `IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample` providing respective stream index.

To adding a new stream to already existing file you need to create a completely new file. One of the options you have is to read already compressed data from existing file you have and write it to the new file using `IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample` method without re-compression. At the same time second stream can be written doing the compression. This way you can create a video and audio MP4 file by taking video from existing file and adding/encoding an additional audio track.